# Commandline options in Gnome 3 launchers

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell

I have several firefox profiles and I would like to be asked which to load when I start firefox.

In Gnome2, I had a launcher with the command

```
firefox -ProfileManager -no-remote
```

How can I do this with gnome-shell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Find the .desktop file for Firefox in `/usr/share/applications/`, copy it to `~/.local/share/applications/`, and edit the `Exec=` line.

You may need to restart GNOME Shell – <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>, `r`.

Comment: If you want two (or more) different launchers, make sure to rename the file from `firefox.desktop` to something else (e.g. `firefox2.desktop`).

Comment: Is it possible to prevent the grouping in the dash somehow. Now all my Firefox profiles go under the same icon.

Comment: For the "Find the .desktop file" step, https://askubuntu.com/a/117342/193272 suggests `sudo updatedb` (if not run recently), followed by `locate *.desktop`